# Gridview pagination. "Download All" Only downloads current page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dotnetzip

I have a grid view showing product images:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:Button ID="btnDownload" runat="server" CssClass="dist-down-button" Text="Download Selected" OnClick="DownloadFiles" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="dist-down-button" Text="Download All" OnClick="DownloadAll" />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="mydatagrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pager" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header" RowStyle-CssClass="rows" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="datagrid_PageIndexChanging" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="No files available">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" />
<asp:Label ID="lblFilePath" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Value") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Text" HeaderText="Image Name" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
</form>
```

Binding function: (matches all the files in the products folder with the product images list from database and show matching products)

```
protected void BindData()
{
    images = GetProductImages();
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/upload/Products/"));
    List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
    foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
    {
        if (images.IndexOf(Path.GetFileName(filePath)) > -1)
        {
            files.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath));
        }
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = files;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
protected void datagrid_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindData();
}
```

Download All function: (look for the gridview list and download all the files listed)

```
protected void DownloadAll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
    {
        zip.AlternateEncodingUsage = ZipOption.AsNecessary;
        zip.AddDirectoryByName(ProductUrl);
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            string filePath = (row.FindControl("lblFilePath") as Label).Text;
            zip.AddFile(filePath, ProductUrl);
        }
        Response.Clear();
        Response.BufferOutput = false;
        string zipName = String.Format("Zip_{0}.zip", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd-HHmmss"));
        Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipName);
        zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

When I click on Download All button it was downloading all the files correctly. **BUT** after I added the pagination the download all is now **only downloading the current page.**

**Note:** The checkbox is for selected download function. As you see I am not looking for checkboxes checked in the DownloadAll function.

Does anyone know why is this happening eventhough I am not looking for any checkbox in my function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn off paging and re-binding the GridView before exporting:

```
protected void DownloadAll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    BindData();

    // ... your code

    GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
    BindData();
}
```

Comment: as simple as that. Thank you. One more question; Isn't this gonna slow down the application since the BindData() is being called multiple times? bind data is pulling out a large list of data.

Comment: It's Depend's on your data...For e.g grid view has 100 records ....Then it will take more...If grid view has 50 records it will take less time as compare to 100 record s

Comment: Yes, there will be some performance loss having to re-bind every time the grid is exported.  Notice that the gridview is re-bound each time the page is updated. You could use Linq `Skip(page * pageSize)` and `Take(pageSize)` if the order the files load in is the same each time. @EvikGhazarian

Answer (score 1):

> In Download All function, you have clearly writing that...take file path
>   only from gridview.. After the pagination...so it only take Current
>   Page Gridview data...not pickup all the data..

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            string filePath = (row.FindControl("lblFilePath") as Label).Text;
            zip.AddFile(filePath, ProductUrl);
        }
```

**Solution:-**

> So, Whenever you binding the Gridview that time hold all data in
>   ViewState..

```
gridView.DataSource = dt;
gridView.DataBind();

ViewState["DownLoadGridData"]=dt as DataTable;

DataTable dt =  ViewState["DownLoadGridData"] as DataTable;

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
    {
        if (row[FilePath] != null) // This will check the null values also (if you want to check).
        {
               // then add filepath 
           string filePath = row[FilePath].ToString();
           zip.AddFile(filePath, ProductUrl);

        }
     }
}
```

**Note:- you can develop your own logic also**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I keep in mind the logic in this for future problems